# Amazon S3 Global service concept

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a client who want confirmation that his data on S3 will only be saved in UK. Amazon S3 is global service and despite i create bucket in Ireland, I guess it replicated to other regions as well to offer 11 nines of durability. This clearly means that my clients data will be copied out of UK as well for replication on AWS side.

Can anyone guide me through the solution for this please OR correct me if I am wrong with the above stated concept.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

[S3 bucket names are globally unique but they exist wholly within one AWS region](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html):

> Objects belonging to a bucket that you create in a specific AWS region never leave that region, unless you explicitly transfer them to another region. For example, objects stored in the EU (Ireland) region never leave it.